# Как определить повторение буквы в строке на языке Golang

Tags: регулярные-выражения, golang

Функция должна определить есть ли повторяющиеся буквы (английские) без учета регистра в строке. Язык Golang.

Мой код:

```go
func IsIsogram(word string) bool {
   return regexp.MatchString(`([a-z]).*\1`, word.toLowerCase())
}
```

Компилятор ругается на регулярное выражение. Не пойму почему, ведь оно составлено верно.

Comment: не поддерживается в goland

Comment: Неверно, RE2 не поддерживает обратных ссылок в регулярных выражениях.

Answer (score 0):

В текущей (1.14) версии языка Go отсутствует поддержка многих возможностей в регулярных выражениях, в том числе, обратная ссылка на группы.

Задача решена так:

```
package isogram

import (
    "strings"
    "unicode"
)

// IsIsogram determines if a word or phrase is an isogram.

func IsIsogram(word string) bool {
    var bitset uint32 = 0
    for _, c := range strings.ToLower(word) {
        if unicode.IsLetter(c) {
            if index := c - 'a'; bitset&(1<<index) == 0 {
                bitset |= 1 << index
            } else {
                return false
            }
        }
    }
    return true
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Так как Golang не поддерживает обратных ссылок (которые используются в представленном регулярном выражении `\1`), то в ответе с [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23968993/11619532) предлагают использовать [golang-pkg-pcre](https://github.com/glenn-brown/golang-pkg-pcre), с более полной поддержкой регулярных выражений.

---

Просто регулярное выражение для поиска повторяющихся букв (от двух) с использованием обратной ссылки на группу

```
(.)\1+
```